# Visual Studio App Center with Flutter App

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I have an app I created using Flutter / Dart / VSCode / Android Studio and wanted to work on it with Visual Studio App Center.

I add an Android app using Java / Kotlin, then add

```
dependencies { def appCenterSdkVersion = '3.2.2' implementation "com.microsoft.appcenter:appcenter-analytics:${appCenterSdkVersion}" implementation "com.microsoft.appcenter:appcenter-crashes:${appCenterSdkVersion}" }
```

to `app/build.gradle` but that's about as far as I get before messing up.

I don't know what 'my app's main class activity' is, I'm guessing it's not **main.dart** as when I put the following code in there I get errors.

```
import com.microsoft.appcenter.AppCenter;
import com.microsoft.appcenter.analytics.Analytics;
import com.microsoft.appcenter.crashes.Crashes;
```

I also can't find `onCreate` anywhere (other than **AndroidManifest.xml** where it's commented out).

I've looked through [Getting started with the Android SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/getting-started/android), but can't figure it out.

Can anyone help me out?

I'm pretty much at the end of my tether so any help would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE**

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    def appCenterSdkVersion = '3.2.2'
    implementation "com.microsoft.appcenter:appcenter-analytics:${appCenterSdkVersion}"
    implementation "com.microsoft.appcenter:appcenter-crashes:${appCenterSdkVersion}"
}
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
import com.microsoft.appcenter.AppCenter;
import com.microsoft.appcenter.analytics.Analytics;
import com.microsoft.appcenter.crashes.Crashes;
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
AppCenter.start(getApplication(), "{My App Secret}",
                  Analytics.class, Crashes.class);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to catch the crashes from Flutter there might be bit tricky for you because technically you'll have 4 types of crashes.

1. Android native crash.
2. iOS Native crash.
3. Dart crash
4. Flutter/Dart errors (i know they are not actual crashes but might mess up the app).

Now for point 1, if you want to add AppCenter you can add the code in the `onCreate` method of the `FlutterApplication`. You can find it `your project -> android -> app -> src -> main -> expand packages`

For iOS Native crash you will have to do it in AppDelegate, which is in `your project -> iOS -> Runner -> AppDelegate`.

For Dart/Flutter crash errors, I don't think there is support from AppCenter. I personally use Sentry and it's doing a pretty good job.

Comment: @NiallDevlin ```Expand packages``` i ment to expand your packages like you do with thee folders and check the content. And to answer your question, Sentry will only help for crashes as far as I know, you can't distribute the app trough Sentry

Comment: I see 2 file in there. **MainActivity.kt** and **AndroidManifest.xml**. In the latter one I see the following commented out. `<!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method. In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->`
That's the only instance of  `onCreate` I could find in my entire project.

Comment: @NiallDevlin that's the one.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still don't think it's working for me. I receive no errors when I run the app, but I also don't see anything under _Analytics_. It also says `This branch has not been configured to build yet` when I click _Build_.

I've updated the original post to show where I added the extra code.

Comment: Is there an image or something that I could maybe use as a reference? @danypata

Comment: @NiallDevlin I'm not sure how much time it will take to see the analytics. But you can simulate a crash in the activity you've added the code. Just do a post delayed execution that will crash.

Comment: Sorry @danypata, I'm pretty clueless with this - how do I simulate a crash and how do a post delayed execution?